# can't run this shell script (get-sh1t-done)

Tags: scripts

So I'm trying to install this [script](https://github.com/icambridge/get-shit-done#readme)

I do

1. copy the folder in `~/Documents/icambridge-get-sh1t-done-1222b6b`
2. change .bashrc (the one in the user directory, is that the right one?) by 
   adding a line `PATH=:~/Documents/icambridge-get-sh1t-done-1222b6b”${PATH}”`
3. set the files in `icambridge-get-sh1t-done-1222b6b` as execs using `sudo chmod +x`
4. type `sudo ./get-sh1t-done` and i get: `/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory`

What is the problem?

Comment: Obviously it does not find php on your computer. Is it installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lekensteyn pointed out in the comment above, you should export the PATH in the `.bashrc`  in the user's home directory like so:

```
PATH="$HOME/Documents/icambridge-get-sh1t-done-1222b6b:$PATH"
```

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` or restart your terminal for it to take effect.

Running the command like `sudo ./get-sh1t-done` will only work if you are in the same directory as the file. Once you've correctly exported the PATH, you can simply run it as `sudo get-sh1t-done`

The error `/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory` is telling you that you need to install PHP. You can install it with:

`sudo apt-get install php5-cli`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it uses PHP but you don't have it installed.
You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

at the command prompt. Then try again to run the script.

Also, there seems to be a python version, which is more likely to be already installed on your system. You could try to use that version instead.

Comment: Link to Python Port(s):
 
https://github.com/dananjayavr/get-shit-done and
https://github.com/leftnode/get-shit-done/blob/master/get-shit-done.py

Comment: that yields: "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php"